# Get error "Error: Invalid RSAES-OAEP padding" trying to decrypt RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa, node-forge

I am trying to decrypt a string in Node.js using the 'node-forge' library. However, when I try, I get the error 'Error: Invalid RSAES-OAEP padding.'
The string was encrypted using the RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding algorithm in Java side and I am trying to decrypt in Nodejs side.

Here is the code I have:

```
const decrypt = (encrypted, key) => {
  const pki = forge.pki;
  let privateKeyFormatted = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
${key}
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;

  const privateKey = pki.privateKeyFromPem(privateKeyFormatted);
  const encryptedMessage = forge.util.decode64(encrypted);
  const decrypted = privateKey.decrypt(encryptedMessage, "RSA-OAEP", {
    md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
    mgf1: {
      md: forge.md.sha1.create(),
    },
  });
  console.log("decrypted", decrypted);
  return decrypted;
};
```

The plain text string is: "5613047438"
The encrypted string is: "IsIrGov7pCrwmsl7Bu+O4hBo9VljexhGQ8bWCOdSD2Q7rVT6PjXcch2R4ZGqAQmezsv+QZsmAGiII270hrXnTTl4OXAvUeZ+UJHsydRXo4DiGhR0S9yr32QB/Rm4hKpCfewTjFR8Acjlvn6OOyyn1cnXB5R54rX2Sl8PidiBzlPwKVygqH9R2npSs+Z3khKvImlpHuu6ESm5GmukOkLRxz4SfJQN76RHJxtsrOHbpvMZpzO2gp9UDyymUwwr0+Lv6pVO4l+n29c/alz+jXmZYkvltOlQHyYFu+J8AZIOK7cXn9lDGx8GJQNG6MdoGhhIrnMFLKKQe04eeiFjQpXrrA=="

I have been reading the documentation of 'node-forge' and followed an example they have for decrypting the algorithm RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding, but it didn't work.
Here is the example provided in the documentation:

```
// decrypt data with a private key using RSAES-OAEP/SHA-256/MGF1-SHA-1
// compatible with Java's RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding
var decrypted = privateKey.decrypt(encrypted, 'RSA-OAEP', {
  md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
  mgf1: {
    md: forge.md.sha1.create()
  }
});
```

Comment: Which provider is used in the Java code? JCA/JCE defaults regarding MGF1 to SHA1, BouncyCastle to SHA256. So try in the forge code SHA-256 for MGF1. If that doesn't solve the problem, post the Java code and non-productive test data (plaintext and ciphertext without keys are useless).